# import pyserial / serial not recognized by python, but dependencies already installed [Mac]

Tags: python, pyserial

Dependencies for pyserial already installed, calling pyserial isn't recognized in python

```
Maxs-MacBook:~ grax$ sudo pip install pyserial
The directory '/Users/grax/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/grax/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Maxs-MacBook:~ grax$ python
Python 2.7.15 (default, May  2 2018, 00:53:27)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.29.1] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyserial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Import Error: No module named pyserial
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python module is called `serial` even though you call pip pyserial. Confusing, yes.

```
import serial
```

The other issue may be that the instance of python you're using isn't the same as the one `pip` is installing for.

See where pip installed the module:

```
$ pip show pyserial
Name: pyserial
Version: 3.4
Summary: Python Serial Port Extension
Home-page: https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial
Author: Chris Liechti
Author-email: cliechti@gmx.net
License: BSD
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Because your Location is `/Library/Python2.7...` pip appears to be installing in the system directory.

However, the version of python you're using (Python 2.7.15) is not the one shipped with MacOSX, so it's probably looking for the python modules somewhere else.

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
```

The version of `pip` is most likely **not** installing there. (pip is not native to MacOS, so it may be using `/usr/local/bin/python` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

You can force pip to install somewhere else using `--target` option:

```
$ sudo pip install --target /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages pyserial
```

Which will put the `serial` module in the location your python is looking.